# How to create GridView with squares items on two columns?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I would like to create a GridView with squares items on two columns which would take the totality of the screen (match_parent).

Every item consists of an imageView and a textView.

Here is the result in image :

[image]

How do I make the items width to be equal to their variable height?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: set android:numColumns="2" and android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform" for gridView

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try that!!

Comment: <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2" />

Comment: Use this link, it will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416847/how-to-force-gridview-to-generate-square-cells-in-android

Answer (score 1):

In your activity or Fragment layout you should have GridView like this:

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
         />
```

And then you should have an Adapter that extends BaseAdapter for example and it's item should be as follow:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/yourDrawable"
        android:layout_margin="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

You need more explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

Use these link, they will help you
[Option 1](http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/11/01/gridview-with-auto-resized-images-on-android)

[Option 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416847/how-to-force-gridview-to-generate-square-cells-in-android)

Comment: Never put only links as your answer because those links usually die, and therefore your answer is useless. Either explain your solution or don't answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is Gridview.

```
<GridView
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:id="@+id/related_contact_grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

This is item. You will inflate this to gridview in Adapter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:text="Tendance"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

</RelativeLayout>
```

> If you want, I can support your work on this Gridview.